# Proof Verification: Problem 20, Ch 3 from Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Can someone please critique my proof? I am a little skeptical of the very last equation I have. Thanks!

Q. Suppose $\{p_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $X$, and some subsequence $\{p_{n_i}\}$ converges to a point $p \in X$. Prove that the full sequence $\{p_n\}$ converges to $p$.

*Proof*. 
    Let $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose $\{p_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $X$. Then, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. 
    \begin{equation}
    m, n > N \implies \left| p_m - p_n \right| < \epsilon/ 2
\end{equation}
    Now, let $\{p_{n_i}\}$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ that converges to a point $p \in X$. Then, 
    \begin{equation}
    n_i > n > N \implies \left| p_{n_i} - p \right| < \epsilon/2
\end{equation}
    Then, (1) and (2) imply that 
    \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \left|p_m - p_n + p_{n_i} - p \right| \leq \left|p_m - p_n\right| + \left| p_{n_i} - p \right| &< \epsilon \\
    \left|p_m + p_{n_i} - 2p_n + (p_n - p) \right| & < \epsilon \\
    \left|p_m + p_{n_i} - 2p_n \right|+ \left|p_n - p \right| & < \epsilon \\
    \left|p_n - p \right| &< \epsilon - \left|p_m + p_{n_i} - 2p_n \right| < \epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
    since $\left|p_m + p_{n_i} - 2p_n \right| > 0$, obviously. This completes the proof.

Comment: How you go from 2-nd line to 3-d?

Comment: @zkutch using the triangle inequality

Comment: From 3-d you can obtain 2d, not reverse. No?

Comment: You should use $d(x, y) $ instead of $|x-y|$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh. What you mean under "$d(x, y)$"

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How would that improve my proof? I find that using $\left|x-y\right|$ makes it easier to use the triangle inequality

Comment: Triangle inequality $|a+b| \leqslant |a|+|b|$ gives, that $|a|+|b| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |a+b| < \epsilon $, but not reverse. Take $\epsilon=2$, $a=2$, $b=-1$:

Comment: In metric spaces the distance between $x, y$ is usually written as $d(x, y) $. The notation $|x-y|$ seems to imply that $x, y$ are real or complex numbers. In a metric space it is not necessary that the operation of subtraction is defined.

Comment: The triangle inequality is one of the key axioms (ie part of definition) of a metric: $$d(x, y) \leq d(x, z) +d(y, z) $$ for all points $x,y,z$ of $X$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Can you, please, write concrete which exact benefit you obtain here by using $d(x, y)$?

Comment: @zkutch: read my comments again. There is no subtraction defined in a general metric space $X$ and hence the expression $x-y$ is meaningless. A fortiori $|x-y|$ is meaningless and therefore wrong. Using $d(x, y) $ is not optional/beneficial /preffered way but that is only way allowed.

Comment: @zkutch: Perhaps you should also refer to text in question ie Baby Rudin. Rudin uses only $d(x, y) $ in context of metric spaces.

Comment: "I find that using |x−y| makes it easier to use the triangle inequality" Its easier to make mistakes too.  the $p_k$ are not numbers so $p_k + p_k$ is *not* defined. And you can't say $p_k + p_k = 2p_k$.

Comment: " Can you, please, write concrete which exact benefit you obtain here by using d(x,y)?"  What benefits is you are saying things that are true and make sense and not a bunch of meaningless nonsense.  If $p,q$ aren't numbers then $p+q$ and $p-q$ do not make any sense and nothing you say actually *works*.

Comment: I'm willing to forgive the use of $|x-y|$ to mean by definition $d(x,y)$ or the distance between $x$ and $y$ provided you *don't* confusing it with subtraction, which you are *NOT* allowed to use.  But $|p_m - p_n +p_{n_i}- p|$ will not make any sense.  Nor does $2p_n$ or $p_m +p_{n_i}-2p_{n_i} +(p_n - p)$ is pure meaningless garbage if $X$ is not a vector space.  WHICH IT IS ***NOT***.

Comment: The benefit of being true and correct outweigh the benefit of being easy but wrong.  And using $|x-y|$ is wrong.  Period.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| p_n - p \right| = \left| p_n -p_{n_i}+p_{n_i}- p \right| \leqslant \left| p_n -p_{n_i} \right| + \left| p_{n_i}- p \right|$$
In metric notation:
$$d(p_n, p) \leqslant d(p_n, p_{n_i}) + d(p_{n_i}, p)$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. I asked you about exact benefit of using metric notation. Often is useful to work in simplified situation and then find possibilities for generalization. My answer using absolute values clears idea for metric space and it is easy to see how to obtain last answer, without subtraction. Anyway, I add metric, also, to answer, for formal exactness. And what about my remark about critique of proof which is main interest of topic starter? imho there is wrongly used general triangle inequality from 2-nd line to 3-d.